# ¿Cómo hacer una Expresión Regular que no permita un espacio en blanco al inicio?

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy buscando una expresión regular que no me permita un primer espacio en blanco y los posteriores, sí, los permita.

[image: http://www.regexr.com/]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tres opciones:

**1. Coincidir con un espacio en blanco al incio, pero negar todo el resultado:**

```
if ( !/^\s/.test(texto) ) {
    ^^^
    el signo de admiración niega al resultado del método .test()
```

- `^` - Coincide con la posición al inicio del texto.
- `\s` - (En minúscula) coincide con 1 espacio en blanco, es decir con `[ \t\n\r\f]`.

No confundirse, el signo de admiración es [el operador lógico `not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Operadores_l%C3%B3gicos#Logical_NOT) de JavaScript, no es parte de la expresión regular.

**2. Hacer coincidir con un caracter que *no sea* un espacio en blanco:**

```
/^\S/
```

- `^` - Coincide con la posición al inicio del texto.
- `\S` - (En mayúscula) coincide con 1 caracter que no es `\s`, es decir con `[^ \t\n\r\f]`.

La contra: no acepta textos vacíos.

**3. Usar una inspección negativa (negative lookahead):**

```
/^(?!\s)/
```

- `^` - Coincide con la posición al inicio del texto.
- `(?!`..`)` - Es una [inspección negativa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead) (*[negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)*), es decir que, sin consumir caracteres, coincide *sólo si no coincide* el patrón que está dentro.

  - `\s` - Coincide con un espacio en blanco.

O sea, todo este regex se puede interpretar como: *coincide con la posición inicial del texto si no está seguida por un espacio en blanco*

---

Código (con estructuras repetidas para simplificarlo):

```js
const regex1 = /^\s/;
const regex2 = /^\S/;
const regex3 = /^(?!\s)/;

let input1 = document.getElementById("inp1");
let input2 = document.getElementById("inp2");
let input3 = document.getElementById("inp3");
let resultado1 = document.getElementById("res1");
let resultado2 = document.getElementById("res2");
let resultado3 = document.getElementById("res3");

//cuando cambia el texto del input
input1.addEventListener("input", function() {
    //ver si NO coincide el regex /^\s/
    if (!regex1.test(input1.value)) {
        resultado1.innerText = "(no coincide) -> Verdadero :-)";
    } else {
        resultado1.innerText = "(coincide) -> ¡Falso!";
    }
});

input2.addEventListener("input", function() {
    //ver si coincide el regex /^\S/
    if (regex2.test(input2.value)) {
        resultado2.innerText = "Coincide :-)";
    } else {
        resultado2.innerText = "¡No coincide!";
    }
});

input3.addEventListener("input", function() {
    //ver si coincide el regex /^(?!\s)/
    if (regex3.test(input3.value)) {
        resultado3.innerText = "Coincide :-)";
    } else {
        resultado3.innerText = "¡No coincide!";
    }
});
```

```html
<p>Prueba negando a <code>/^\s/</code>:</p>
<input type="text" id="inp1">
<code id="res1" r></code>
<p>Prueba de <code>/^\S/</code>:</p>
<input type="text" id="inp2">
<code id="res2"></code>
<p>Prueba de <code>/^(?!\s)/</code>:</p>
<input type="text" id="inp3">
<code id="res3"></code>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias loco!, me sirvio de mucho la ayuda, saludos y cuidese.